# Do I require an amplifier?

Tags: voltage, amplifier, bluetooth, headphones

I am planning to do a simple DIY project to replace the cable on my [Sennheiser HD 598](https://en-in.sennheiser.com/high-end-headphones-audio-stereo-hifi-hd-598), which has 50Ω impedance, with a [bluetooth receiver](https://www.amazon.in/Electronic-Spices-Bluetooth-Receiver-Transmitter/dp/B07V3WS9XN), a 3.7V 1000mAh battery (and a [charging board](https://www.amazon.in/Electronic-Converter-Overcharge-Over-Current-Protection/dp/B082MPDWRD)).

My calculation for how long it will last, according to Ohms law,
$$
3.7V = I\times50Ω \implies I = 74mA
$$
which should last me 13.5 hours on a 1000mAh battery.

My questions:

1. Is this correct or am I missing something?
2. Do I need an Amp?
3. Any general suggestions on how you would do it. This is my first time.

Comment: 50 ohm impedance into the speaker itself does not mean that the current draw is 74 mA.

Comment: How would I go about calculating the correct current draw?

Comment: Check the datasheet for the receiver you want to use, if available. If not, you may need to just purchase it and experiment/measure.

Comment: @nanofarad do I need an amp?

Comment: Same answer again - check the datasheet of the part.

Comment: Poor specs and reviews. Seems like a mismatch for Sennheisers

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Can you please outline what recommended specs I should look for?

Comment: Whats more important quality or cost or performance with BT buds?

Comment: Quality. If by performance, you mean, how long it'll last on the battery, can I strap in a bigger battery and let it last longer?

Answer (score 0):

> My calculation for how long it will last, according to Ohms law,

The current consumed by the headphones depends on the supply voltage, which itself depends on the volume setting (louder means more current) and the music (quiet music means less current).  Without a datasheet you would have to measure the current draw.

> Do I need an Amp?

The Amazon page you linked says that an amplifier is required.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The page does say that an amplifier is required, but several videos that use this receiver don't use any amp. They were very small headphones and some that had 10Ω impedance. Does the requirement of an amp depend on the impedance of headphones?

Comment: @AbdulsattarMohammed If that is a line output, using too low impedance will result in distortion and loss of bass frequencies. Higher impedance will not have this problem, but are often less sensitive and so will be very quiet. Without a lot more information I can't give you a more specific prediction, but high sensitivity and moderately high impedance headphones are more likely to work, although probably not as well as you would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth module has tiny ceramic output coupling capacitors. Combined with 50 ohms headphones (quite a low resistance load) you can expect no bass (due to low capacitor value) and lots of distortion (due to X7R ceramics or worse).

This hints that the module is supposed to just have a line output and be used with an amp, which means the output opamp will be low current and it will probably not be able to drive 50 ohms properly.

If you've got the big Sennheisers and not earbuds, I'll assume you care about good sound, and this thing probably isn't going to deliver that.

Comment: thanks for the response! Can you recommend a suitable module? Or just spec it out, I'll find something that meets those specs.

Comment: Why not use the phone's headphone jack?

Comment: that's what I'll resign to, if this doesn't work out. But, I wanted to give it a go as my first DIY project.